# Create classes dynamically

Tags: vb.net, web-services

There are three web services I have to call to do some work.  They all accept an object (different objects) as an input parameter and an object (different objects) as an output parameter.  Please see the database table below:

```
CREATE TABLE WebServices (id int identity not null, webaddress varchar(50), classname varchar(30), inputParameter varchar(30), outputparameter varchar(30), function varchar(30))

INSERT INTO WebServices (classname, webaddress, inputparameter, outputparameter,function) values ('WebService1', 'http://localhost/webservice1.asmx', "object1", "object2", "function1")
INSERT INTO WebServices (classname, webaddress, inputparameter, outputparameter,function) values ('WebService2', 'http://localhost/webservice2.asmx', "object3", "object4", "function2")
INSERT INTO WebServices (classname, webaddress, inputparameter, outputparameter,function) values ('WebService3', 'http://localhost/webservice3.asmx', "object4", "object5", "function3")
```

In the code I would construct the classes from the values in the database.  Is this advisable/possible? I believe I could do it with reflection.

Alternatively I would create three new classes the usual way and use a factory to return the appropriate class as follows:

```
If id=1 then
return new WebService1
ElseIf id=2 then
return new webservice2
ElseIf id=3 then
return new webservice3
End If
```

I am wandering, which option is better.

Answer (score 2):

While it is possible to generate classes on the fly by using the CodeDom classes, it's ugly and ill-advised for this scenario.  If you can, I would recommend changing the behavior of the WebService so that it returns key/value pairs or an XML document containing the structured data as a string.  If you really must return an object with particular properties, I would recommend looking into always returning an object of the same class, but just having that class completely override the SOAP serialization to output itself however you need it to.  If all else fails, I would use your second option before going down the dynamic classes via CodeDom route.

Comment: Thanks +1.  The web services are developed by third party companies.  I use them to delete information from their databases (which are Oracle or SQL Server).  I send an instruction to delete ID 1 and the web service deletes everything linked to ID 1.  The web services accept different objects and return different objects.  Does this change your answer?

Comment: @w0051977 Actually, I misread your question.  I thought you were writing the webservices and dynamically building the objects that were being returned.  That makes a little more sense now.  Do the webservices use SOAP formatting or the .NET Binary Formatting?  If they use SOAP formatting, then I believe you have a lot of control over the formatting of the classes, which is an interesting option.

Comment: I would recommend spending some time reviewing the proxy classes (the designer code) that is generated automatically by the web reference.  You don't have to use the auto-generated proxy classes.  You can write your own client classes using all the same underlying framework tools, which would give you much more flexibility.

Comment: What do you mean by binary format? I know what binary format is but I thought all web services were serialised as soap?

Comment: Check out the [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx) and the [SoapFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.soap.soapformatter.aspx).  Standard web services do use SOAP, but I believe with WCF you have the choice to use that or binary.

Comment: I am very interested in your comment: "I would recommend spending some time reviewing the proxy classes".  Are you saying it is ok to modify the classes that are automatically generated e.g. add a function called "executedelete", which accepts a common arguement and returns a common arguement in each webservice?

Comment: You certainly could, or you could write a proxy class from scratch and use it without even adding a web reference.  You don't have to use the built in tools and designer code at all.  Or, if all you need to do is add an additional method, do it in a `Partial Class` so that you don't have to touch the designer generated code.  Then you could update the reference without losing your custom code.

Comment: I am looking into what you said above.  Could you have a look at my other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101307/accessing-web-services-uniformly?  An example would help.

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection is always slower than hard-coding (reflection takes time) so if speed is better, then option 2 is the answer.  If writing more generic code and possibly writting it faster is better, then option 1 is better.